# Android Intent Filter pathPattern exclude url

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

Not sure if this is possible, but hoping someone has a solution.

I am trying to have my Android app intercept urls of the form mydomain.com/abc but not mydomain.com/mp3/id

Is it somehow possible to exclude certain paths, with pathPattern?

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="mydomain.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/.*" /> />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Since `pathPattern` is not a full regex engine, I doubt that you want you want will be possible.

Comment: Thats what I'm thinking, just hoping there is a way

Answer (score 0):

pathPattern works more like glob than like regexp. If you *really* mean mydomain/abc, you should be able to specify android:host="mydomain.com" android:pathPattern="abc", but my guess is that you mean

Match mydomain.com/x

Don't match mydomain/x/y

I don't think it's possible. If it is, it probably involves some use of pathPrefix.

Comment: Any idea if there's now a way to implement the `Don't match mydomain/x/y` idea?